# How do I customize the admin cache page?

Tags: magento

Running Magento 1.4 and I want to customize the admin Cache Storage Management page. I looked at the files in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/cache` , but none of them actually seem to have the content that is generated on the cache page. I also looked in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml` but didn't see anything in there to override. If someone could clue me into where the files might be or how I might override the page, I would be indebted to you.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? There are a couple of ways to affect content in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

- Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Cache.php
- Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Cache/Edit.php
- Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Cache/Form.php

Override them as normal.

Comment: Cache.php the file I was looking for was located here: /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block